# I want to get a unique value only from duplicate rows

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

My aim is to select a rows that have a distinct LeaveApplied where duplicates are present on remaining columns, see the example table "Leave" below:

| LeaveApplied | title | department | bank | joiningDate | exitDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | hsbc | 14-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |
| 17-Mar-24 | Associate | production | hsbc | 13-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |
| 17-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | kvb | 14-Mar-24 | 13-Mar-24 |
| 18-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | hsbc | 14-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |
| 19-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | hsbc | 14-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |
| 20-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | kvb | 14-Mar-24 | 13-Mar-24 |

I tried below query but did not help me.

```
SELECT LeaveApplied, title, department, bank, joiningDate, exitDate
    COUNT(*) occurrences FROM leave
GROUP BY title, department, bank, joiningDate, exitDate HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

> Ended with error: Column 'Leave.LeaveApplied' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

The desired result would be:

| LeaveApplied | title | department | bank | joiningDate | exitDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | hsbc | 14-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |
| 18-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | hsbc | 14-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |
| 19-Mar-24 | Associate | quality | hsbc | 14-Mar-24 | 14-Mar-24 |

Can I have query or guidance to get desired result?

Comment: Please only the **single** RDBMS you are using as a start... cos the solution will be different for each.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)